# dockerize gunicorn, nginx, django in single container

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

i am trying to dockerize my django project using gunicorn and nginx. The setup works on my machine, but i can't get nginx to work with the unix socket inside the image.

[i followed this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04). Since i can't use systemctl inside the container, i tried to run gunicorn as a CMD. To start Nginx, i tried restarting the container, but then my CMD is not restarted (i think?) and the container shuts down.

**How should i properly reload the nginx service inside the docker container using my dockerfile?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use systemctl inside a container. Either configuring a systemd daemon inside the container, or using the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) to do without. I am using that regularly to run multiple service inside one container.